# Why would a process use over twice as many CPU resources on a machine with double the cores?

Tags: multithreading, macos, cpu, multicore

I'm hoping someone could point me in the right direction here so I can learn more about this.

We have a process running on our iMac Pro 8-core machine which utilises ~78% CPU.

When we run the same process on our new Mac Pro 16-core machine it utilises ~176% CPU.

What reasons for this could there be? We were hoping the extra cores would allow us to run more processes simultaneously however if each uses over double the CPU resources, surely that means we will be able to run fewer processes on the new machine?

There must be something obvious I'm missing about architecture. Could someone please help? I understand I haven't included any code examples, I'm asking in a more general sense about scenarios that could lead to this.

Comment: The key is not why it uses so much CPU, it is why it uses so little.  That can normally only happen when the program is bogged-down by waiting for I/O.  Say the disk drive.  When you get a "better" machine then you also get faster peripherals.  Say an SSD instead of a spindle drive.  So now it is not bogged-down as long and can drive the CPU load up.  Use a profiler to get hard facts instead of guesses.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the CPU thread manager tries to use as much CPU as it can/needs. If there are more processes needing CPU time, then the cycles will be shared out more sparingly to each. Presumably your task runs correspondingly faster on the new Mac?

Answer (score 1):

The higher CPU utilization just indicates that it's able to make use of more hardware. That's fine. You should expect it to use that hardware for a shorter period, and so more things should get done in the same overall time.

As to why, it completely depends on the code. Some code decides how many threads to use based on the number of cores. If there are non-CPU bottlenecks (the hard drive or GPU for example), then a faster system may allow the process to spend more time computing and less time waiting for non-CPU resources, which will show up as higher CPU utilization, and also faster throughput.

If your actual goal is to have more processes rather than more throughput (which may be a very reasonable goal), then you will need to tune the process to use fewer resources even when they are available. How you do that completely depends on the code. Whether you even need to do that will depend on testing how the system behaves when there is contention between many processes. In many systems it will take care of itself. If there's no problem, there's no problem. A higher or lower CPU utilization number is not in itself a problem. It depends on the system, where your bottlenecks are, and what you're trying to optimize for.